# Unable to read from Excel file in F# using OpenXml

Tags: excel, f#, openxml-sdk

I'm trying to figure out, how to use F# to read data from an existing Excel file.
I found this (rather old) question, but have problems running it:
[Reading cell contents in an Excel file with F# and Open XML SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34267464/reading-cell-contents-in-an-excel-file-with-f-and-open-xml-sdk)

It seems that either the compiler or the SDK (or both) changed with regard to this line:

```
let theSheet:Worksheet = ((WorksheetPart.wbPart.GetPartById(firstSheet.Id)).Worksheet
```

(I know that there is a typo with the brackets; just wanted to quote the original source)

Even without the additional bracket and the following code:

```
// Learn more about F# at http://fsharp.org

open System
open System.Linq
open System.Data
open System.Windows
open DocumentFormat.OpenXml // Also install DocumentFormat.OpenXml from nuget
open DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging
open DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet
open Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel

let toStr s = Printf.TextWriterFormat<unit>(s)

//Read the value of a single cell by string coordinates (Open XML SDK)
let read_value_openxml (file_path_and_name:string) (column:int) (row:int):string =
    let stream = new System.IO.FileStream(file_path_and_name, System.IO.FileMode.Open, System.IO.FileAccess.Read, System.IO.FileShare.ReadWrite)

    // Open the spreadsheet document for read-only access.
    let document = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(stream, false)

    // Retrieve a reference to the workbook part.
    let wbPart = document.WorkbookPart

    // Find the sheet with the supplied name, and then use that sheet object to retrieve a reference to the first worksheet.
    let firstSheet:Sheet = wbPart.Workbook.Descendants<Sheet>().Where(fun s -> (toStr s.Name.Value).Equals("Sheet1")).First()


    // Retrieve a reference to the worksheet part.
    let wsPart:Worksheet = wbPart.GetPartById(firstSheet.Id.ToString())

    // Use its Worksheet property to get a reference to the cell whose address matches the address you supplied.
    let theCell = wsPart.Worksheet.Descendants<Cell>().Where(fun c -> c.CellReference = column + row).FirstOrDefault()

    "test"
```

The compiler complains about the line

```
let wsPart:Worksheet = wbPart.GetPartById(firstSheet.Id.ToString())
```

saying that

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   FS0001  This expression was expected to have type
    'Worksheet'    
but here has type
    'OpenXmlPart'   HelloF  C:\Users\user\Documents\workspace\FSharp\HelloF\HelloF\Program.fs   32  Active
```

I tried to explicitly cast the value from `OpenXmlPart` to `Worksheet` like this too:

```
let ws:Worksheet = (wbPart.GetPartById(firstSheet.Id.ToString()):OpenXmlPart) :?> Worksheet
```

With the same result though.

So I looked up the issue [in the SDK Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/dd920313(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN), which [provided the following example code (in VB)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/dd920313(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN#adding-the-sample-code-to-the-solution):

```
...
' Reference to Excel Worksheet with Customer data. 
custID = _
   workSheets.First(Function(sheet) sheet.Name = "Customer").Id()
aacustSheet = DirectCast( _
   document.WorkbookPart.GetPartById(custID), WorksheetPart)
```

Here a `DirectCast` is used for this part of the code.

What is the proper way to use this SDK in F#?
I foud a couple of examples on how to create a new Excel File via creating new WorkBookParts, but unfortunately no working example for just reading.

Comment: Could  EPPlus be an option for you? It works flawlessly.

Comment: yes i guess it could; where could I find a tutorial or example project using it with F#? I am just learning the language and not too savvy with it's .NET integration. couldn't find something this fast...

Comment: I can post a simple example with EPPlus as an answer.

Comment: would appreciate that thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered the Excel type provider?

https://fsprojects.github.io/ExcelProvider/

Comment: Is the workbook path always statically encoded in the file when using the type provider?
or is there a convenient method to set this dynamically, that I am missing?

Comment: @FabianSchneider the path is encoded to get the metadata e.g. columns as types in F# for this is sufficient to provide a smaller excel with the same columns.   For the run type file you can pass it as the constructor of the type.   e.g. type Excel1 = Excel<"metadatasample.xsls">    let runtime = Excel1("/mydir/productionfile.xslsx")

Answer (score 1):

You could use EPPlus for that. Here is a very simple example in a script:

```
#r @"C:\Users\flavi\.nuget\packages\epplus\5.0.4\lib\net45\EPPlus.dll"

open OfficeOpenXml
open System.IO

let sheetFile = new FileInfo(@"C:\somefolder\someExcelFile.xlsx")
let sheetName = "SomeSheet"

using (new ExcelPackage(sheetFile)) (fun p ->
    let wk = p.Workbook                     //the workbook
    let ws = wk.Worksheets.[sheetName]      //a worksheet
    let someCell = ws.Cells.[1,1]           //a single cell
    printfn "%A" someCell.Value)
```

You can then explore other methods and properties to get things done.

Comment: how would I best speciey the `LicenseContext`? (As described here)[https://epplussoftware.com/developers/licenseexception]

Comment: Never used that before, but I guess you would have to insert something like this before the "using" function: ExcelPackage.LicenseContext <- System.Nullable(LicenseContext.NonCommercial)

Comment: perfect, that solved it thanks. don't you get the `LicenseException` when running this example?

Comment: No. I guess that's because I'm not attaching a debugger. The documentation says: "this exception is only thrown when a debugger is attached, so you don't have to configure this in a production/release environment".